# how to link multiple comments to a request in a database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, table-relationships

So I am developing this request management system web app in ASP.net, C#, SQL server and am currently designing the database. My question is that, I want a request to have multiple comments from different users. I have a Requests table and a Users table. How can I link multiple comments from multiple users to a request?

Should I create a separate table for Comments? then what...

thanks!

Comment: can you please provide more details ?? Schema details at least

Comment: if your specified details not holding comments you might have to create another table and get the output

Answer (score 0):

You can model a [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) with a junction table, e.g. `Comments`, where each tuple of the relation has a foriegn key to the `Requests` table primary key, and a foriegn key to the `Users` table primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a separate comments table, with keys of request and user. You will have to implement this in some form, so doing it as an explicit comments table makes sense.

This is a standard many-to-many relationships, and, as devdigital points out, you would normally model this with a junction table. Sometimes this is simply a linking table, but in this case, you can make it a comments table explicitly.

In your coding, you can then create objects of user with a list of comments, and request with a list of comments. And the comments can have a reference to the users and requests, but don't load these in directly, as you will have circular references!